# Assigning Jquery Method to variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, methods

I'm curious if it's possible to assign a jquery method to a variable and if it is, how could I do it? I've tried:

```
function testing(data){

$specialVar = $(data).find()

$specialVar("#test").html("testing")
}
```

is this even possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do this:

```
function testing(data){

    return function(elem){ return $(data).find(elem); };
}

$specialVar = testing(data);
$specialVar("#test").html("testing");
```

Comment: Perfect! the return function(elem){ return $(data).find(elem); }; line is exactly what i needed

Answer (score 0):

I guess you could do something like:

```
$specialVar = $.find;
$($specialVar.call(data, "#test")).html("testing");
// alternative: $specialVar.call(data, "#test")[0].innerHTML = "testing";
```

Wouldn't recommend it, though.

Comment: Close but no cigar. I'm just trying to shorten $(selector).find("#test") to be something smaller like $var("#test")